# Fetch returns only one item in collection

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, left-join, fetch

Table info:

The **Image** table contain a foreign key **mediaid** for its the parent table **Media**

```
----------
id  | mediaid | url
========================
104 | 103     | IMG_PATH
383 | 103     | IMG_PATH
384 | 103     | IMG_PATH
395 | 103     | img_path
```

The **Media** entity holds a collection of Images :

```
private Set<Image> images  = new HashSet<Image>(0)`;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "media", targetEntity = Image.class ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Image> getImages() {
   return images;
}
```

---

Image entity snippet:

```
private Media media;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "mediaId")
public Media getMedia() {
    return media;
}
```

---

I implemented the following query, that should return a Media object with a  collection of all images whose fk matches its **id** provided.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Media> cqObject = cb.createQuery(Media.class);
Root<Media> rootEntry = cqObject.from(Media.class);

rootEntry.fetch(Media_.images, JoinType.LEFT);              
Predicate predicate = cb.equal(rootEntry.get(Media_.id), id);           
cqObject.select(rootEntry).where(predicate);        
Media _fetcheMedia = em.createQuery(cqObject).getSingleResult();
```

The collection for the Media object returned only ever contains one image item. I know for certain that database contains multiple Image items for the specified Media.

*Note **Media_** is simply a  metamodel class that represents the Media entity

Hibernate out for  Media object  with id=103

```
select media0_.mediaId as mediaId1_8_0_, 
    images1_.imageId as imageId1_6_1_, 
    media0_.active as active2_8_0_, 
    media0_.created as created3_8_0_, 
    media0_.description as descript4_8_0_,
    media0_.listType as listType5_8_0_, 
    media0_.parentId as parentId6_8_0_, 
    media0_.propertyTypeId as property7_8_0_, 
    media0_.seasonId as seasonId8_8_0_, 
    media0_.status as status9_8_0_, 
    media0_.userId as userId10_8_0_, 
    images1_.active as active2_6_1_, 
    images1_.created as created3_6_1_, 
    images1_.imageTypeId as imageTyp5_6_1_, 
    images1_.imageUrl as imageUrl4_6_1_, 
    images1_.mediaId as mediaId6_6_1_, 
    images1_.mediaId as mediaId6_6_0__, 
    images1_.imageId as imageId1_6_0__ from media media0_ 
    left outer join image images1_ on media0_.mediaId=images1_.mediaId where media0_.mediaId=103
```

Comment: Ok, when you get the Media object, is the images Set loaded with entity or its a proxy that you need to lazy initialize?

Comment: I'm assuming it is lazy init by default and the rootEntry.fetch(Media_.images, JoinType.LEFT) forces a fetch on the collection.

Comment: the criteria seems alright.. can you run in debug mode and post the query that is generated?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski , I added the hibernate query generated from the JPA code above.

Comment: Have you overridden `hashCode` and `equals` of `Media` in any way?

Comment: @crizzis  just did that, in the Image class .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake on my part, I forgot to override the hashcode and equals method for the Image entity . Added them and it know works as it should.

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Image other = (Image) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```